SSRS - Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities
I am troubleshooting an error in SSRS
we want to alter a subscription and set it to the next 5 min from now, but when it gets there it does not run.
other than that,
I see these error messages in the reporting services execution logs:

0-27!4270!07/01/2024-12:54:47:: e ERROR: Throwing
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException:
,
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.NotEnabledException:
The requested functionality is not currently enabled.;

question:
How to enable these diagnostics utilities?
I can query the ReportServer database, I see the errors, but not the details:
select r.* 
from reportserver.dbo.ExecutionLog3 r
where status <> 'rsSuccess'
order by r.TimeStart DESC


when I open the file rsreportserver.config
that in my environment lives at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer
I can only see the following line related to diagnostics:
   <Add Key="WatsonDumpOnExceptions" Value="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException"/>


Did you check "rsreportserver.config" file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer? There are utility elements like this
<Extension Name="Shared Dataset Cache Update Extension" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SharedDatasetCacheUpdatePlanHandler,ReportingServicesLibrary"><Event><Type>SharedDatasetCacheUpdate</Type></Event> </Extension>

Maybe update dbo.Schedule table solve your problem. Update your scheduleId
column NextRunTime = DATEADD(minute, 5, GETDATE())
